# How to Implementing boost factor on conditional query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch, using version 2.3

I have document having values for employee, their department and salary. I want to apply boost factor based on department and their salary condition based i.e. salary less than 1500$ should get higher ranking. For example.

```
"Department" : "Technical",
"Boost": "2"
"Salary" : "<=1500",
"Boost":"1"
```

### Expected output:

```
Name: ABC,
Department: Technical
Salary: 1000

Name: XYZ
Department: Technical
Salary:  1200

Name: PQR
Department: Technical
Salary: 1600
```

Please suggest how can I write this query in elastic.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I had tried using script_field for salary, but it was returning only true / false value; however I am looking for complete resultset, with name, department and salary as well.